# Add ALSA to Android

Tags: android, alsa

I would like to understand how an application like [**AlsaMixer**](http://de.appszoom.com/android_applications/tools/alsamixer-root-required_bzprk.html) or [**MixGet, mixer widget with alsa**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gilsken.mixget&hl=de) is working.

Specially, I would like to develop an application which makes use of the "/etc/asound.conf" which would be available with ALSA.

Has anyone more knowledge on this? How can I "build" ALSA for every Android-device?

I personally have tested those applications on my own Samsung Galaxy Nexus which natively uses "tinyalsa" and on an "HTC Desire" which uses something with "/dev/msm_audio_out" (don't know  what this is exactly).

It seems that those apps require root, ok no problem, but they work without larger modifications and on a large range of devices).

Thanks in advance for your help, I've read hundreds over hundreds of docs and found no real informations.

Answer (score 0):

If an Android device

- actually uses ALSA drivers; and
- is rooted (so that your app can access the device files),

then you could the NDK to access the ALSA libraries.
In that case, ALSA works just like on any other machine.